# Obter trajeto usando a localização do utilizador até ao Marker pré-definido(javascript google-mapsv3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou a utilizar a resposta que está na pergunta do seguinte link: [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586916/google-maps-directions-from-users-geo-location)

E não estou a entender o que preciso de colocar na linha abaixo onde está o comentário:

```
map = new google.maps.Map( /*creates Map variable*/ document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions /*Creates a new map using the passed optional parameters in the mapOptions parameter.*/);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("map")
```

Nesta parte do código vc coloca o id da div onde será feito o mapa, neste exemplo o id da div é "map". Você pode substituir pelo id da sua div.

```
mapOptions
```

Esses é um objeto com as opções do mapa que vc vai criar, vai passar o objeto que criou anteriormente no exemplo

```
var mapOptions = //Sets map options
 {
   zoom: 15,  //Sets zoom level (0-21)
   center: coords, //zoom in on users location
   mapTypeControl: true, //allows you to select map type eg. map or satellite
   navigationControlOptions:
   {
     style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL //sets map controls size eg. zoom
   },
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //sets type of map Options:ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, TERRIAN
 };
```

Nesse caso está setando o zoom, centro e outras configurações do seu mapa.
Sem os comentários ficaria apenas:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

O exemplo só está comentando o que é cada informação. Apenas precisa passar a div correta e o objeto com as configurações que você precisa.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela  resposta no entanto nessa linha estou a ter o seguinte erro: js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null_.Kf @ js:1qg @ js:1(anonymous function) @ VM71:39 . O erro foi tirado na console do browser

Comment: O id da sua div está correto? é o mesmo que está ai no getElementById?

Comment: Realmente tinha errado o nome da Div. Você resolveu meu problema. Obrigado